# MySql unknown column in where clause but column does exist

Tags: mysql

I can

```
select a_column from table_1
```

and get results but when I

```
select * from table_2 where table_2.a_column = table_1.a_column
```

I get an error

```
unknown column table_1.a_column in where clause
```

If I do

```
select * from table_1 where table_1.a_column = table_2.a_column
```

I get

```
unknown a_column table_2.a_column in where clause
```

The columns absolutely do exists, and they absolutely do have overlapping data. Why is this happening? I've tried searching for an answer because I thought this would be common but I can only find answers relating to typos which is not the case.

Comment: You need to express this as a `JOIN` or select on both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of **Joins**, the concept is still vast and you can have a look over it [**here.**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

The example below just demonstrates a **simple join** which would serve as a solution to your present situation only. There are much more you need to look upon in the link I posted above.

Also, be careful while

> table_2.column = table.column, column values must be matching in both
>   the tables

```
select * from table_2  
join table2 on table1
where table_2.column = table.column
```